# How can I account for this UI discrepancy between iOS 10 and iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios10, ios11

[image: iPhone 6 Plus iOS 11]

[image: iPhone 6 Plus iOS 10]

The first picture is iPhone 6 Plus iOS 11 and the second picture is iPhone 6 Plus iOS 10. Why is there a discrepancy in the distance between the status bar and the back button? And how can I account for this in my code?

here's the code

`[backButton.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:margins.topAnchor constant:5].active = YES;`

Comment: Are you using the SafeArea?  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need something like:

```
[backButton.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor constant: 5.0]
```

where `self` is the view controller you're displaying the button in.

The discrepancy comes from how Apple has changed layout guides to more easily account for the nav bar, tab bar, iPhoneX notch, etc.